# create an instance of HttpServletResponse to capture response to a buffer

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

I am calling a method the takes a `HttpServletResponse` object and then writes to the response body. Is there a `HttpServletResponse` implementation that captures the response to a byte array instead of actually writing/flushing the response to the client making the request (so I can update the content and send it to the HTTP client)? I know I can write my own implimentation using `HttpServletResponseWrapper` but wanted to see if there are any library/utils that do this already instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: If you have control over the code that writes and sends you could refactor that into 2 methods one that calculates the response in bytes and another that calls that method and then writes the response and flushes. Then you just call the first method and do what you wan with the response.

Comment: Unfortunately that method is in a third party jar. So refactoring is not an option.

Comment: is that 3rd party jar common or have documentation. is your method supposed to return HTML XML or JSON. there are plenty of librarys that will let you generate those from POJO's

Comment: Can you add a [Filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html)?  This is designed to do what you're ultimately wanting to do.

Comment: @stdunbar I can add a filter but that would add complexity. I would have to parse the entire response just to find the spot where I need to add my content. With a ResponseWrapper, I can simply add my content right after the call to the third party method and then call the third party method again with different params.